# Указать путь к папке

Tags: java, android

Надо, чтобы пользователь указал путь к папке с файлами через визуальный файловый менеджер. Нашел следующий код.
Но тут и не папка, а файлы. Да и я не могу понять, куда записывается сам путь.

Может кто подскажет другие способы решения.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
intent.setType("*/*");      //all files
// intent.setType("text/xml");   //XML file only
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);

try {
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select a File to Upload"), a);
} catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
    // Potentially direct the user to the Market with a Dialog
    Toast.makeText(this, "Please install a File Manager.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

**UP!**

Добился выбора файла и получения его пути.
Но по прежнему не могу выбрать папку.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    intent.setType("*/*");      //all files
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);

    try {
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select a File to Upload"), REQUEST_CODE);
    } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
        // Potentially direct the user to the Market with a Dialog
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please install a File Manager.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Uri uri = data.getData();
        Toast.makeText(this, uri+"", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: посредством чего указывается путь? сложно понять вопрос если честно)

Comment: через ФайлМенеджер. код, что я скинул, вызывает какой-то дэфолтный менеджер. я вижу в нем список файлов и могу тыкнуть на любой файл и он свернется. но непонятно ни как указать папку, а не файл. и не понятно, что он делает с файлом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для работы с файловым менеджером нужно использовать такую функцию как `onActivityResult()` сюда будут приходить данные о пути файла/папки на которую вы нажали, вот например:

```
public void startPickAFile(String title, String buttonText) {
    Intent intent = new Intent("org.openintents.action.PICK_FILE"); 
    intent.setData(dataUri); // A file URI for suggested file name or starting directory. Can also be left empty. 
    intent.putExtra("org.openintents.extra.TITLE", title); // String
    intent.putExtra("org.openintents.extra.BUTTON_TEXT", buttonText); // String
    if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) { 
      startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) { 
      // handle result
    }
}
```

дальше уже обрабатываете полученный путь так как вам нужно:

```
 Uri uri = data.getData();
```

Вот полезные источники:

1. [ссылка_1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33478911/android-getting-file-name-and-path-from-onactivityresult)
2. [ссылка_2](http://www.openintents.org/action/org-openintents-action-pick-file/)
3. [доки](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result)

### UPDATE

Дальше все предельно просто, вам нужно проверять что именно пользователь выбрал - файл или папку:

```
File file = new File(path);

boolean exists =      file.exists();      // проверяем на наличие
boolean isDirectory = file.isDirectory(); // это папка?
boolean isFile =      file.isFile();      // это файл?
```

есть второй вариант:

```
Path file = new File(path).toPath();

boolean exists =      Files.exists(file);        // проверяем на наличие
boolean isDirectory = Files.isDirectory(file);   // это папка?
boolean isFile =      Files.isRegularFile(file); // это регулярный файл?
```

и дальше если это папка то вы проводите над ней действия по извлечению нужных вам файлов.

### UPDATE_2.0

Для того чтобы выбрать именно папку есть такой способ:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE);
i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i, "Choose directory"), 1);
```

и дальше обрабатываете:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    switch(requestCode) {
        case 1:
            Log.i("Test", "Result URI " + data.getData());
            break;
    }
}
```

этот способ должен вам подойти вероятнее всего.

Comment: это к файлу. а мне нужна папка. и я уже потом буду вытаскивать из нее файлы, с нужным мне расширением.

Comment: извиняюсь за непросветную тупость, но я упираюсь в intent.setData(dataUri); как указать корень всего телефона ?

Comment: `File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();` - но это уже насколько я понял устаревший способ https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html

Comment: у меня получилось выбрать файл, но не вашим методом. но папку по прежнему не могу выбрать =(

Comment: Либо вы что-то не так делаете либо я не могу понять что именно вам нужно сделать))

Comment: я обновил мейн пост.

Comment: а зачем вы лепите `intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);` везде и постоянно?

Comment: не знаю) я еще разбираюсь в этом. но проблема не в нем же.

Comment: обновил ответ :)

Comment: класс!!! это то, что надо! можно последний вопрос, это уже для общего развития?
когда я использую ваш 'Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE)', то у меня показывает ТОЛЬКО мой телефон и выбрать можно только папки.
когда использую 'Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT' - все файлы во всех местах - кроме памяти телефона еще вылазят диктофон, галереия, ГуглДиск, диктофон, ГуглФото и тд и тп.
что надо использовать, чтобы выбрать файл, но показывало только память телефона, как в вашем коде?

Comment: `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE` используется для отображения дерева каталогов, а `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` для выбора файла, можно попробовать указать определенное место где вы можете выбирать папки и все)) Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый.

Comment: а не подскажите, как получить не `Uri`, а полный путь `Path` ?

Comment: вот тут я тоже пытался получить путь https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1074272/Как-получить-путь-хранилища-android-10

Answer (score 0):

Благодоря @Andrew и еще покопавшись в инете, нашел следующее решения для разных ситуаций:

Для выборки одного файла используем:

```
   Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
   intent.setType("*/*"); // тут можно задать тип файлов
```

Если хотим выбрать несколько файлов - добавляем

```
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
```

А для выбора папки используем

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE);
```

После определения файлы или папки, одиночный или мультивыбор, дописываем

```
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select a File to Upload"), REQUEST_CODE);
```

Теперь можно перейти к обработчику.

Если мы выбирали 1 файл, то просто:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Uri uri = data.getData();
        Log.e("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!", uri + "");            
    }
}
```

А если несколько, то надо обрабатывать массив. В примере я беру только 1ый элемент. А try-catch нужен для того, если вы выбрали 1 элемент, то происходит ошибка в  `ClipData a = data.getClipData();` поэтому если мы ее ловим - элемент один и можно использовать обычный `Uri uri = data.getData();`

```
 @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Uri uri;
        try {
            ClipData a = data.getClipData();
            uri = a.getItemAt(0).getUri(); // тут только берется первый элемент!!! 
        } catch (Exception e) {
            uri = data.getData();

        }
        Log.e("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!", uri + "");
    }
}
```