# Как получить путь хранилища android 10?

Tags: android

Получал путь раньше так:

```
root = File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().absolutePath)
```

но после релиза 10 android это дело стало deprecated. Нашел такой вариант в сети:

```
String destPath = mContext.getExternalFilesDir(null).getAbsolutePath();
```

или такой:

```
val externalStorageVolumes: Array<out File> =
                ContextCompat.getExternalFilesDirs(applicationContext, null)
val primaryExternalStorage = externalStorageVolumes[0]
```

но они оба возвращают такое:

```
/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.my/files
```

а мне нужно:

```
/storage/emulated/0/
```

я вижу два варианта:

1. Отсекать ненужные части пути и в итоге получать `/storage/emulated/0/`
2. Захардкодить корень сразу и не получать его через функцию.

Может есть еще какие-то варианты решения данной проблемы?

Comment: deprecated как бы намекает что пора забывать про файлы на внешних накопителях и готовиться к Андроид 11. В котором можно будет использовать только то, что возвращают варианты с контекстом или Document/Provider API + SAF.

Comment: @woesss, а не могли бы вы объяснить немного если не сложно?) Просто насколько я вижу то что я привел в вопросе не работает, второй вариант это было через intent у меня, но вы вот еще какие-то способы привели про которые я слышу впервые)

Comment: Я и имел ввиду через интент, весь [вот этот](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider?hl=ru) велосипед с квадратными колёсами, с которым и связываться не хочется. Но ребята из гугла пошли по схеме управдомши: *"А если не будут брать, то мы им отключим газ"*.

Comment: то есть saf это имеется в виду делать через intent и дальше в onActivityResult и тд?

Comment: просто я в onactivity result никак не могу получить путь файла и думал что вы имели в виду другой способ)) получать пытаюсь так -  `val urii = data!!.data` и дальше так `val src = urii!!.path`

Comment: Нет путей и файлов - нам предлагается про них забыть и писать приложения в стиле клиент-сервер. Вы же не можете напрямую получить доступ к файлам на сервере - вместо этого вы обращаетесь к REST-обёртке и она выдаёт вам данные. Здесь тоже самое, только вместо REST провайдеры и SAF. Долго это всё объяснять - будет время почитайте гайды, а если надо сделать "вчера" - забейте и пишите по-старинке пока работает. @Deprecated не значит, что это **уже** не работает, но намекает, что в следующих версиях может быть вырезано.

Comment: @woesss, суть как раз в том что если брать `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().absolutePath` уже не работает)) в 10 у меня на теле не выводит список файлов))

Comment: Попробуйте освоить класс [`DocumentFile`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/documentfile/provider/DocumentFile.html) - он должен вам помочь вывести список. Запросите `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE` и создайте экземпляр методом [`fromTreeUri`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/documentfile/provider/DocumentFile.html#fromTreeUri(android.content.Context,%20android.net.Uri)) - дальше смотрите документацию по методам

Comment: Добавьте в манифест android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true", должно на десятке работать.. У меня нет смартфона с 10, но на эмуляторе работает, а без этой строки не работает.. Если вырежут, то я не знаю что делать, у меня все завязано с Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), переделывать не осилю..

Comment: @Alex455, я переделал)) посмотрите ответ ниже, все работает нормально :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот решение моей проблемы, может кому пригодится:

```
private fun showFileChooser() {
        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT)
        intent.type = "*/*"      //all files
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE)

        try {
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, resources.getString(R.string.attachment_dialog)), 1)
        } catch (ex: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please install a File Manager.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }
```

и дальше:

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            val documentFile: DocumentFile = DocumentFile.fromSingleUri(this, data!!.data!!)!!
            val string = data.data?.let { uri -> contentResolver.openInputStream(uri).use { it!!.readBytes() } }
            if (!mNames.contains(documentFile.name)){
                uploadFiles(documentFile.name!!, Base64.encodeToString(string, Base64.NO_WRAP))
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(this, R.string.message_about_attached__file, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }

        }
    }
```

Наверное нужно немного объяснить что здесь происходит)) Данный функционал нужен для возможности добавления в json массив файлов с последующей отправкой адресату в письме. Это прикрепления файла если в общем говорить. В функции `onActivityResult` я вызываю функцию которая выгружает файлы в массив. Предварительно я кодирую файл в `Base64` и так же получаю имя данного файла. Может кому пригодится :)