# Исправить устаревший Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() в sdk 29

Tags: android

Подскажите пожалуйста, как переписать этот код, чтобы заменить устаревший
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(). 
Как этот код исправить, чтобы он не был устаревшим? 
Сейчас основная папка с подпапками создаётся в корне диска, и не удаляется с программой, как это сделать в версии sdk 29?

```
String myFolder = "Map Locs Files";
String myFolder_Images = "Map Locs Files/Images";
String myFolder_Cam = "Map Locs Files/Images/.Img of Camera";
String myFolder_Gall = "Map Locs Files/Images/.Img of Gallery";
String myFolder_Points = "Map Locs Files/Points";
String myFolder_myIcons = "Map Locs Files/.Icons-"; 

public File Directory_Catalog_of_pathFilesImage; 
public File Directory_Catalog_of_pathFilesTXT_Points_in_Map; 
public File Directory_Catalog_of_pathFilesTXT_name_desc_Map; 

String full_Path_catalog_folder_Camera; //Полный путь до файлов 
String full_Path_catalog_folder_Gallery; //Полный путь до файлов
```

в onCreate:

```
  Directory_Catalog_of_pathFilesImage = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    Directory_Catalog_of_pathFilesTXT_Points_in_Map = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    Directory_Catalog_of_pathFilesTXT_name_desc_Map = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    Directory_Catalog_of_pathFilesTXT_Routes = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(); 


    full_Path_catalog_folder_Camera = Directory_Catalog_of_pathFilesImage + "/" + myFolder_Cam + "/";
    full_Path_catalog_folder_Gallery = Directory_Catalog_of_pathFilesImage + "/" + myFolder_Gall + "/";
    full_Path_catalog_folder_myIcons = Directory_Catalog_of_pathFilesImage + "/" + myFolder_myIcons + "/";
```

Само создание:

```
//создание папок и файлов
public void create_folder_and_files(){
    // Создаем папку и 2 подпапки для хранения тхт файла точек, и изображений
    File folder = new File(Directory_Catalog_of_pathFilesImage, myFolder);
    if (!folder.exists()) {
        folder.mkdir();
    }
    File folder1 = new File(Directory_Catalog_of_pathFilesImage, myFolder_Images);
    if (!folder1.exists()) {
        folder1.mkdir();
    }
    File folder2 = new File(Directory_Catalog_of_pathFilesImage, myFolder_Cam);
    if (!folder2.exists()) {
        folder2.mkdir();
    }
    File folder3 = new File(Directory_Catalog_of_pathFilesImage, myFolder_Gall);
    if (!folder3.exists()) {
        folder3.mkdir();
    }
    File folder4 = new File(Directory_Catalog_of_pathFilesImage, myFolder_Points);
    if (!folder4.exists()) {
        folder4.mkdir();
    }
    File folder5 = new File(Directory_Catalog_of_pathFilesImage, myFolder_myIcons);
    if (!folder5.exists()) {
        folder5.mkdir();
    }
}
```

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics

Comment: мне не нужна никакая камера, мне надо создавать папки и подпапки в корне диска, и получить к ним путь в версии SDK 29, так как  Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() не работает на андроид 10..

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1074272/Как-получить-путь-хранилища-android-10

Comment: Чем вас не устраивает папка приложения, которую можно получить через контекст [`context.getExternalFilesDir("Map Locs Files")`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#getExternalFilesDir(java.lang.String))? Просто нормальный, вменяемый способ работать с файлами во внешней памяти закрыли как раз из-за того, что все гадят в корень диска и юзеры жаловались, что в этой помойке не могут найти свои файлы.

Comment: Мне нужно чтобы папка(со всем содержимым) не удалялась вместе с приложением.. Было же нормально все.. Я так и не пойму, в корень диска вообще нельзя будет записывать?

Comment: @woesss сейчас с SDK 28 все работает, или потом эту возможность отключат, хранить в корне диска? Мне надо, чтобы моя папка не удалялась с программой!