# Android больше не дает записать в /sdcard/emulated/0

Tags: java, android, localstorage

Я задаю этот вопрос снова (так как на StackOverFlow уже много таких вопросов), потому что в android запретили использовать `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();`, открыв её только для чтения.

Моя задача заключается в резервном копировании базы данных. Чтобы это сделать, я использовал `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();`, который уже был `@Deprecated`, но позволял туда записывать.
Варианты, которая дает официальная документация не помогает, так как она предлагает использовать `Enviroment.DIRECTORY_`, но она записывает только в пакет моего приложения, те после удаления БД не сохранится.

Auto BackUp мне не подходит, так как мне надо сделать ручное восстановление и сохранение (через кнопки, проще говоря)

Есть ли способ сохранить базу данных ВНЕ моего приложения? (Например: в папке `/Customers`)

P.S. Я пытался использовать /storage/Customers/my_file, но `mkdir()` и `mkdirs()` возвращает `false`

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1074272/Как-получить-путь-хранилища-android-10

Comment: Вопрос не в том, как получить путь, а в том, чтобы записать туда файл. Теперь это сделать невозможно

Comment: а почему нельзя делать резервную копию на диск например, потому что если приложение удалено, то какой смысл в резервной копии бд?

Comment: Вы не поняли, я пока не использую облако. Я сохраняю файл на `/sdcard/emulated/0`, где файл сохраняется независимо от того, удалено ли приложение или нет. Для восстановления я его читаю

Comment: один из вариантов - можно отключить очистку файлов приложения после удаления, потому что пользователь может удалить папку с бд если вы ее в доступном месте сохранили

Comment: @woesss, возможно я конечно что-то не так понял)) но в `build.gradle` есть такая конструкция - `task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}`

но возможно это предназначается для выполнения других задач

Comment: @woesss, протупил немного :(

Comment: @AdisAlagiс, сам ещё не разбирался , но предполагаю решение по пути: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider?hl=ru#create дальше через `ContentResolver` открыть поток на запись

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В Android Manifest нужно добавить следующую строку:

```xml
<application
    ...
    android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" />
```

Comment: Начиная с Андроид 11 это не будет работать. Советую уже начать осваивать `SAF (Storage Access Framework)` и `DocumentFile`.