# Android getExternalStorageDirectory deprecated

Tags: android, kotlin, android-scoped-storage

У меня имеется класс файловый менеджер. Он работает нормально, но только до Android 9.0 включительно.

На Android 10.0 он возвращает пустой список.

Я думаю это из-за метода getExternalStorageDirectory(), который объявлен Deprecated в Android 10.0

Что можете посоветовать, без изменения существующей логики

```
class FileManager {

    constructor(context: Context) {
        val directory: File = if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED == Environment.getExternalStorageState())
//            Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
        else ContextCompat.getDataDir(context) ?: throw Exception("File does not exist!")
        rootDirectory = directory
        navigateTo(directory)
    }

    lateinit var currentDirectory: File
    var rootDirectory: File

    fun navigateTo(directory: File): Boolean {
        /**
         * Проверяем является ли файл директорией
         */
        if (!directory.isDirectory) {
            Log.d("FileManager", "${directory.absolutePath} is not a directory!")
            return false
        }

        /**
         * Проверим, не поднялись ли мы выше rootDirectory
         */

        if ((directory != rootDirectory) && rootDirectory.absolutePath.contains(directory.absolutePath)) {
            Log.w(
                "FileManager",
                "Trying to navigate upper than root directory to " + directory.absolutePath
            );
            return false
        }

        currentDirectory = directory
        return true
    }
    fun isRootDirectory(): Boolean{
        if (currentDirectory == rootDirectory)
            return true
        return false
    }


    fun navigateUp(): Boolean {
        return navigateTo(currentDirectory.parentFile!!)
    }

    fun getFiles(): ArrayList<File> {
        val items = ArrayList<File>()
        val files = currentDirectory.listFiles()
        Log.d("files", files.size.toString())
        files?.let {
            items.addAll(currentDirectory.listFiles())
        }
        return items
    }
```

}

Я пробовал:

1. context.filesDir - возвращает какие - то служебные файлы или библиотеки (например .Fabric, в котором находится crashlytics.sdk) - Не подходит
2. context.obbDir - пусто
3. context.cacheDir - как я понял cache моего приложения - Не подходит
4. context.dataDir - это как я понял папка моего приложения - Не подходит
5. context.externalCacheDir - пусто
6. context.externalCacheDirs и context.externalMediaDirs не подходят так как возвращают список, а не один элемент

Есть еще варианты?
И да, у меня минимальный API 18

**Update**

Нашел атрибут для application `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` но это костыль.
Как сейчас по нормальному файловый проводник делать?

Comment: у меня была такая же проблема, https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1074272/Как-получить-путь-хранилища-android-10, переходите на intent :)

Comment: `Как сейчас по нормальному файловый проводник делать?` Теперь для таких приложений нужно получать разрешение у гугла в Play Console

Comment: @Andrew, а если файлового проводника у пользователя нет, то и в вашем приложении он не может отправлять файлы, хм

Comment: @IR42 не подскажете раздел соответствующий, найти никак не могу

Comment: к сожалению нет, я, можно сказать, просто процитировал одного из разработчиков https://youtu.be/UnJ3amzJM94?t=1996, сам с этим не работал

Comment: это по-умолчанию проводник идет, системный, а он вероятнее всего в большинстве будет

Comment: @Andrew, тогда почему в VK, telegram, viber, whatsapp написали свой файловые проводники, через Fragment, раз системный должен быть всегда, да мы можем сказать, чтобы ради единого дизайна, но у меня приложение используется в компании для заработка, и их не устроит, что я на Android 10 кидаю в сторонние программы, хотя мне прям покажут, вот в телеге все работает, сделай также =)

Comment: После ноября 2020 и в телеге не будет :)

Answer (score 2):

Как временная мера, чтобы найти новое решение и пересмотреть подход,
оставьте `targetSdkVersion 28`, до ноября 2020 года без проблем дотянуть :)

> Android 10 (API level 29)
>   August 3, 2020: Required for new apps
>   November 2, 2020: Required for app updates

А вообще как раньше уже не будет. Это теперь называется `Scoped Storage`
https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage#scoped-storage

Т.е. доступ как раньше только к своим файлам.
Нужно что-то еще -- `MediaStore API` и `Storage Access Framework` в помощь.
По ссылке выше много информации по теме.

Comment: прочитал http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/theory/external.php, аж плакать хочется, но пока добавил флаг в application

Comment: я не могу понять, а внутреннюю память через total comander будет видно? Смогу я через проводник менять и добавлять свои файлы в своём приложении, ну в каталоге Android/data/com...my_app/files/?

Comment: @Alex455, вы имеете в виду при подключении телефона к компьютеру? Вопрос автора был о другом.

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja а есть возможность как-нибудь поменять UI стандартного андроидовского файлового проводника ?

Comment: @VanechikSpace неверное никак, не встречал такой информации.